# CSS media query not working while shrinking browser window

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have made sure the CSS file isn't cached and that the id/class names are correct. When I shrink my browser down to a size within that range it doesn't apply the CSS.

This is the CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
{
    #body2 .content
    {
        max-width: 690px;
    }

    #navWaypoint #header
    {
        width: 690px;
    }
}
```

I haven't experienced this issue before.

Comment: Looks good to me bud! its valid code.

Comment: I know however when I shrink my browser down to a size within that range it doesn't apply the CSS.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess and say you should be using min-width, not min-device-width if all you're doing is shrinking your browser

Comment: The reason it's not happening when you shrink your browser window size down is not because your code is invalid, it's because it's device width, not window width. You will need to use Chrome's Overrides in Developer Tools to change Device metrics to something within that size.

Comment: Damn that was the problem, thanks SynXsiS and setek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are shrinking your browser windows to evaluate your code here is your answer.

`min-device-width` and `max-device-width` refers to **display resolution**.
While `min-width` and `max-width` refers to the size of the **browser window**.

Use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`  and hopefully you will get what you want.